# CA signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption or ecdsa-with-SHA256

Tags: certificate-authority, ecdsa

I need to update a CA that is about to expire, currently is using `Signature Algorithm 256WithRSAEncryption` and I am thinking in using `ecdsa-with-SHA256` with something like:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 3650 \
  -newkey ec:<(openssl ecparam -name prime256v1) \
  -keyout certs/CA.pem -out certs/CA.crt -subj "/CN=myCA"
```

Besides updating, recreating existing certificates, wondering if there is something that I should take care of when using `ecdsda` signatures?

Comment: CA key rollovers can be complicated if you start going down the cross-cert backwards-compatibility route, but I don't think there's anything specific to ECDSA that you need to worry about.